# Can Orders be filtered by metafield using the Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

There's no mention of this capability on the Shopify [API Docs Page](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order), but I'm wondering if anyone may have experience with an undocumented means of doing this.

Edit for further explanation: The idyllic imaginary solution would be something like `GET /admin/orders.json?metafield[metafield_key]=metafield_value`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is pretty easy to figure out. An order is a resource. Metafields are also a resource. You never get an orders's metafields when you ask for the order resource using the API. So now you're stuck making an API call for each orders metafield resources.

So your filter will be slow. Same problem makes using variant metafields bad, as you need to make an API call to get them, hence any scripting relying on them will never be real-time fast but always O(N) slow...

As @alex mentions, you could use your own DB to filter... so that answer is the only one that makes any sense for any App needing to work WWW.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your thoughts. I updated the original question a little to clarify - obviously I don't want to be making O(N) API calls to fetch metafields. Just hoping that I might be able to have the Orders endpoint do the work to filter on a Metafield key/value the same way it can filter on eg `status`.

One avenue that wasn't immediately obviously to me when I asked the question is that I could potentially filter the Metafields endpoint itself on key/value and owner resource type - I will look into this.

Comment: That would be sweet eh. An API Metafield endpoint where you could structure a query to return all metafields assigned to the Orders resource, with a namespace filter of 'foo' for example. I am thinking that kind of support is far far out there though...

Comment: Definitely! The API documentation does tend to suggest that it's possible but I've been fiddling around with cURL requests and haven't got anything working as yet.

Comment: Hey @GavinBallard did you ever figure out if you could leverage the Shopify Metafields endpoint to retrieve all the orders with some specific metafield value from the API in a performant way?

Comment: Nothing has changed. You ask for your Order from the API, then the metafields. Then you filter by iterating through them. Nothing speedy there.  There is no filter on metafield namespaces (at least not yet).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can add metafields to Shopify orders:

```
   PUT /admin/orders/#{id}.json
{
 "order": {
"id": 450789469,
"metafields": [
  {
    "key": "new",
    "value": "newvalue",
    "value_type": "string",
    "namespace": "global"
  }
]
}
}
```

You can definitely store the orders in a database and then filter them by metafields.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't really answer my question. I know that I can use metafields on orders or store and filter them with a local database.

Comment: Well, David does agree with me :-(